# Dropdown items should be bold if related records present in Datagrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I am working on wpf MVVM application, there are 2 controls combobox and Datagrid . Based on the value selected in Combobox , the Datagrid itemsource should be filtered. This is working fine.
The next requirement is , if item in Combobox have atleast one filtered value in Datagrid then item text in Combobox should be set bold.
Can any one suggest in what optimised way this requirement can be implemented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create an `Attached` Property to get `ItemsSource of DataGrid`, with its `PropertyChangedCallback()`.
2. Apply this property to your control used to display lookup items. It can be `TextBlock` showing country names in your `ComboBox`.
3. You will get your callback called with `DataGrid.ItemsSource` and `TextBlock`, simply loop through the list, and set `FontWeight` to `Bold`.

Sample :

**Window2.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfAdvanced.Window2"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:cc="clr-namespace:WpfAdvanced"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfAdvanced"
        Title="Window2" Height="300" Width="300">

    <StackPanel x:Name="Grd">
        <Button Content="Add" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="Cmb">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" local:Window2.ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource, ElementName=Dgrd}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>

        <DataGrid x:Name="Dgrd">            
        </DataGrid>

    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

**Window2.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfAdvanced
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window2.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window2 : Window
    {
        DataGrid b = new DataGrid();
        ArrayList countries = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList lookupCountries = new ArrayList();



        public static ArrayList GetItemsSource(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (ArrayList)obj.GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty);
        }

        public static void SetItemsSource(DependencyObject obj, ArrayList value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ItemsSource.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ItemsSource", typeof(ArrayList), typeof(Window2), new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(myCallback)));

        private static void myCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBlock tb = (TextBlock)d;
            ArrayList v = (ArrayList)e.NewValue;
            bool found = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < v.Count; ++i)
            {
                dynamic o = v[i];
                if (o.Name == tb.Text)
                {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (found)
                tb.FontWeight = FontWeights.ExtraBold;
        }



        public Window2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            dynamic o1 = new { Name = "UK", Capital = "London" };            
            countries.Add(o1);
            dynamic o2 = new { Name = "USA", Capital = "New York" };
            countries.Add(o2);
            dynamic o3 = new { Name = "INDIA", Capital = "New Delhi" };
            countries.Add(o3);
            dynamic o4 = new { Name = "INDIA", Capital = "Shimla" };
            countries.Add(o4);

            Dgrd.ItemsSource = countries;

            dynamic c1 = new { Name = "UK" };
            lookupCountries.Add(c1);
            dynamic c2 = new { Name = "INDIA" };
            lookupCountries.Add(c2);
            dynamic c3 = new { Name = "SRILANKA" };
            lookupCountries.Add(c3);

            Cmb.ItemsSource = lookupCountries;
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Dgrd.ItemsSource).Filter = grdFilter;
        }

        private bool grdFilter(dynamic obj)
        {
            dynamic i = Cmb.SelectedItem;

            return (obj.Name == i.Name);
        }
    }   
}
```